# Jquery droppable using centre of dragged element rather than cursor position

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a table where each row is draggable using JQuery ui. These rows can be dropped into another droppable element on the page. I'm using the cursorAt option to set the cursor to be centred on the x axis and just to the left of the dragged row whilst dragging so not to obscure the data . My problem is I can only drop the content when the centre of the draggable object is inside the droppable one. I need it to be able to drop the draggable object based upon the cursor position. I.e the cursor is inside the droppable object when dragging but the actual draggable object(helper) is outside.

Hopefully this makes sense...

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add what code you have tried or a link to a fiddle example. I suspect you need to adjust the tolerance option: https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-tolerance

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a go and create a fiddle if needs be